# Automatically comparing Java profiling results for a single unit test

Tags: java, profiling

I want to run a single unit test and collect its "profiling" information: how often every method was called, how many instances of certain class were created, how much time did it take to execute certain method/thread, etc. Then, I want to compare this information with some expected values. Are there any Profilers for Java than let me do this (all this should be done automatically, without any GUI or user interaction, of course)?

This is how I want it to work:

```
public class MyTest {
  @Test
  public void justTwoCallsToFoo() {
    Profiler.start(Foo.class);
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    foo.someMethodToProfile(); // profiler should collect data here
    assertThat(
      Profiler.getTotalCallsMadeTo(Foo.class, "barMethod"), 
      equalTo(3)
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: How is this question different from the multiple other 'can you recommend a Java profiler?' questions on SO? I use YourKit with Intellij, and just profile the (individual) unit tests as per any other run...

Comment: I want to profile a class/method **inside** a unit test - without any IDEs or any visual interaction with profilers.

Comment: Do you mean to say that your unit test will execute the profiler, collect the output, and the unit test will pass/fail based on the profiling data (e.g. how many times a method was called)?  If so then I believe the question could be clarified to make it clear that you want to invoke a profiler *programmatically* and get its output via an API.  For example, I read "I want to compare" as you, the human, doing it manually.

Comment: @AndrzejDoyle I updated the question with a Java example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that this could be done with a J2SE built-in [HPROF profiling tool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/samples/hprof.html).

```
java -agentlib:hprof=cpu=times MyTest
```

It produces a text file formatted like this:

```
CPU SAMPLES BEGIN (total = 126) Fri Oct 22 12:12:14 2004
rank   self  accum   count trace method
   1 53.17% 53.17%      67 300027 java.util.zip.ZipFile.getEntry
   2 17.46% 70.63%      22 300135 java.util.zip.ZipFile.getNextEntry
   3  5.56% 76.19%       7 300111 java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass2
   4  3.97% 80.16%       5 300140 java.io.UnixFileSystem.list
   5  2.38% 82.54%       3 300149 java.lang.Shutdown.halt0
....
```

Then it's easy to parse the file and extract the methods you're interested in. The solution is completely free and JSE built-in, which is a great benefit comparing to other tools.

Comment: Seems like the link you provided by now redirects to the oracle homepage... you might update it to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/samples/hprof.htmlm

Comment: hprof is no longer available after Java 8.

Answer (score 3):

Capturing snapshots of profiling information automatically is possible with several Java profilers, you have to add VM parameters to the Java start command to load the profiler and you have to tell the profiler to record data and save a snapshot on exit.

In [JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html), you could use the ["profile" ant task](http://resources.ej-technologies.com/jprofiler/help/doc/offline/ant.html) to do this. It takes the profiling settings from a config file that is exported from the JProfiler GUI. You can use the [Controller API](http://resources.ej-technologies.com/jprofiler/help/doc/offline/javadoc/com/jprofiler/api/agent/Controller.html) to start recording and save a snapshot.

Then you have two choices:

1. You can use the **jpcompare** command line utility or the corresponding ["compare" ant task](http://resources.ej-technologies.com/jprofiler/help/doc/export/antComparisons.html) to compare the snapshot against a known baseline. There are [several comparisons available](http://resources.ej-technologies.com/jprofiler/help/doc/export/cmdlineComparisons.html). You can export the results as HTML or in a machine-readable format (CSV/XML).
2. You can extract data from the snapshot with the **jpexport** command line utility or the corresponding  ["export" ant task](http://resources.ej-technologies.com/jprofiler/help/doc/export/antExport.html). Then you can write your own code to analyze the profiling data from a particular run.

For a limited set of profiling data, it is actually possible to use the JProfiler API to write your own profiler that does something like the `Profiler.getTotalCallsMadeTo(Foo.class, "barMethod")` in your example. See the `api/samples/platform` example in a JPofiler installation. You would get the information from the hot spot data.

However, for making assertions on whether a specific method was called I would suggest to take an AOP-based approach. Using a profiler-based approach is appropriate for detecting performance regressions.

Disclaimer: My company develops JProfiler.

Comment: Sounds like a solution, thanks. Btw, do you have a Maven plugin?

Comment: No, we don't have a maven plugin yet.

Comment: Another disadvantage is that it's not a free product